# Filtering by geometry type in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely, filter

I have a GeoPandas `GeoDataFrame` with a `geometry` column that contains both `POLYGON`s and `MULTIPOLYGON`s. How do I filter only `MULTIPOLYGON`s?

I used this approach, but I am sure there might be better ones:

```py
# 'at' because it's data about Austria
at_geometries.loc[at_geometries["geometry"].astype("str").str.startswith("MULTI")]
```

Comment: Is that slow or what is the problem?

Comment: It's a bit slow (because it has to parse as strings the whole list of points in the geometry) but I could not find any other way. I guess there is no "official"/built-in way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many solutions (see [How to filter a geodataframe by geometry type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60820256/835653) for example)

With `.loc` as you but with `geometry.type` or `geom_type`

```
gdf0 = gdf.loc[gdf.geometry.geometry.type=='MultiPolygon']
gdf0
    ID                 geometry
0    1  MULTIPOLYGON (((244697.452 1000369.231, 244827...
1    5  MULTIPOLYGON (((244912.829 1000603.336, 245042...
2    8  MULTIPOLYGON (((244732.568 1000040.313, 244862...

gdf0= gdf.loc[gdf.geometry.geom_type=='MultiPolygon']
idem
```

With `apply`,`lambda` and `type`

```
gdf1 = gdf[gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x : x.type=='MultiPolygon')]
gdf1
    ID                 geometry
0    1  MULTIPOLYGON (((244697.452 1000369.231, 244827...
1    5  MULTIPOLYGON (((244912.829 1000603.336, 245042...
2    8  MULTIPOLYGON (((244732.568 1000040.313, 244862...
```

With `geom_type`

```
gdf2 = gdf[gdf.geom_type=='MultiPolygon']
gdf2
    ID                 geometry
0    1  MULTIPOLYGON (((244697.452 1000369.231, 244827...
1    5  MULTIPOLYGON (((244912.829 1000603.336, 245042...
2    8  MULTIPOLYGON (((244732.568 1000040.313, 244862...
```

With `geometry.type` as Kadir Şahbaz

```
gdf3 = gdf[gdf.geometry.type=="MultiPolygon"]
gdf3
    ID                 geometry
0    1  MULTIPOLYGON (((244697.452 1000369.231, 244827...
1    5  MULTIPOLYGON (((244912.829 1000603.336, 245042...
2    8  MULTIPOLYGON (((244732.568 1000040.313, 244862...
```

Comment: As usually @gene aggregates all the possible approaches. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you, this is really great! I did not know geopandas had this great attribute(s). And thank you for the thorough reply!

Answer (score 11):

Using `geometry.type=="MULTIPOLYGON"` is (15 times in my computer)
faster.

```
at_geometries[at_geometries.geometry.type=="MULTIPOLYGON"]`
```