# Check if geometry field in GeoPandas geodataframe have any row with specific type

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, geodataframe, geometry-data-type

This question is related to: [Filtering by geometry type in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413795/filtering-by-geometry-type-in-geopandas)

I need to check if my geodataframe contains 'MultiPolygon' type.

Below is my attempt, but it doesn't work. According to [documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.geom_type.html) it should work, I think. How can I do it?

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon, MultiPoint, LineString, MultiLineString

geo_dict= {"ogc_fid":[58], "geometry":[MultiPolygon([Polygon([(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2)])])]}
gdf= gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_dict)

result1 ='MultiPolygon' in (gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result2 = MultiPolygon in (gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result3 ='Polygon' in (gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result4 = Polygon in (gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
print(result1) # prints False
print(result2) # prints False
print(result3) # prints False
print(result4) # prints False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a list, simply use

```
'MultiPolygon' in gdf['geometry'].geom_type.values
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, it is enough to add `list()`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon, MultiPoint, LineString, MultiLineString

geo_dict= {"ogc_fid":[58], "geometry":[MultiPolygon([Polygon([(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2)])])]}
gdf= gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_dict)

result1 ='MultiPolygon' in list(gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result2 = MultiPolygon in list(gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result3 ='Polygon' in list(gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
result4 = Polygon in list(gdf['geometry'].geom_type)
print(result1) # prints True
print(result2) # prints False
print(result3) # prints False
print(result4) # prints False
```

Comment: You don't need a list, simply use `'MultiPolygon' in gdf['geometry'].geom_type.values`

Comment: @gene Thank you, if you add this solution as separate answer, I will accept it.